# jQuery: Direct child of $(this)

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to, somehow, select a direct child of $(this)?

I have:

```
var obj = $(this);  
$("ul", obj).css('width',s*w);
```

And need it to act like this `obj > ul`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`$(this).children('ul')` returns a list of direct children.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NfN6C/1/ jsFiddle of your code .... it matches all the `ul`s in `$(this)`

Comment: And whats wrong with that? No one asked for the first child, only for direct !!! don't mess around with down-votes if you are not sure what you are saying!

Answer (score 18):

Try the following:

```
$(this).find("> ul")
```

Answer (score 9):

The jQuery constructor can take a second parameter which can is used to override the context of the selection.

```
$("ul", this);
```

And if you just want the first I think you could do

```
$("ul:first", this)
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me ;)

```
$('> ul',this)
```

Answer (score 2):

this may work too (depends on what exact situation are you in maybe)

```
$(this).find('>*:eq(0)')
```