# How to get immediate children in jQuery when you already selected object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery, I know I can do this

`$("#box > a")`

but what if I did

`var box = $("#box");`

Using the variable `box`, how can I get the `> a` part from it?

Thanks

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: [`$("#box").children("a")`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186523/jquery-direct-child-of-this)

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev find will get all the children, i'm looking for immediate children.

Comment: @omega `.find` will get anything that matches a selector

Answer (score 4):

Use `find()` like following.

```
box.find('>a')
```